# Autodesk Forge - Handling Parameter Updates and Versions

Tags: autodesk-forge

In order to pull the properties for a file, we need the complete urn for the file as shown here ...

```
urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.fwefwfwefmwklfm424knk24n2j?version=1
```

However, on my platform users can alter parameters which are then sent to Fusion 360 where those numbers alter the user parameters driving the cad design. They then have to save the file for these changes to be recognized.

This then creates a new version number.

Doesn't this then mean that when I try to download the properties for that file with that urn, I am downloading old data?

In addition to this, if I am sending a base encoded urn from my client side to my server, I would then have to decode that string to even see the version number attached to it.

...

To get the latest data, I need the latest version number so that I can change this urn into the base encoded urn. How can I check to see if a new version exists and what the highest version available is? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve all versions of an item through [GET   projects/:project_id/items/:item_id/versions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-versions-GET/) and pick out the latest of them by their `versionNumber` and `lastModifiedTime`

```
"createUserName": "John Doe",
        "createTime": "2016-04-01T11:12:35.000Z",
        "createUserId": "BW9RM76WZBGL",
        "lastModifiedUserName": "John Doe",
        "lastModifiedUserId": "BW9RM76WZBGL",
        "versionNumber": 2,
        "lastModifiedTime": "2016-04-01T11:15:22.000Z"
```

Comment: So, if a user wants to pull properties for a Fusion 360 file, they have to send an encoded URN. Part of that URN is the version number. Is there any way to prompt Fusion to return properties from the latest version of a file?

Comment: Unfortunately a version number will need to be specified - but you can keep track of the latest version yourself by taking advantage of [webhooks](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/tutorials/create-a-hook-data-management/) to notify you when a version is created or modified, see supported events [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/data_management/)

Comment: Thats a really good suggestion. I will have to implement that. For now, I just decided to use to Get end point above, since I don't expect the request to be made often.